# Formatting a long list to 80 columns

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
  try:
    for key in copy['KnownNetworks'].keys():
      if copy['KnownNetworks'][key]['SSID_STR'] == networkDict['name']:
        networkDict['uuid'] = copy['KnownNetworks'][key]['Unique Password ID']
        print 'Found existing reference to wireless password uuid: %s' % networkDict['uuid']
        found = True
  except:
    print 'Key KnownNetworks not found'
  # Clean up top level key

  keychain = '/Library/Keychains/System.keychain'
  arguments = [security,"add-generic-password",'-a',networkDict['name'],'-l',networkDict['name'],'-D','Airport network password','-s',networkDict['uuid'],'-w',networkDict['pass'],'-T','group://Aiport','-T','/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app','-T','/Applications/System Preferences.app','-T','/usr/libexec/airportd',keychain]
  addKeychainPassword(arguments)
  users = '/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users'
  listing = os.listdir(users)
  for plist in listing:
```

I have a formatting question, is the example above, is there a better way to format the arguments list declaration? Its a subprocess call , so I need it to be a list, but I guess I could convert it to a dictionary and then back to a list. My main goal being that I would want it to fit in the 80 col standard on most unix scripts. Any techniques that you would like to share in terms of clean code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For lines over 80 columns, you can break them into multiple lines. Here it's easy as you've got a list.

```
arguments = [security,
             'add-generic-password',
             '-a', networkDict['name'],
             '-l', networkDict['name'],
             '-D', 'Airport network password',
             '-s', networkDict['uuid'],
             '-w', networkDict['pass'],
             '-T', 'group://Aiport',
             '-T', '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app',
             '-T', '/Applications/System Preferences.app',
             '-T', '/usr/libexec/airportd',
             keychain]
```

Here not only do you get the warm glow of satisfaction of complying with the Python style guide, but it's *much* easier to see the arguments being passed when the code is formatted this way.

The official guide to Python layout is [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It has other examples of splitting long lines.